# Getting no response from an ajax call

Tags: javascript, c#, jquery, ajax, json

I have been trying to get this ajax call to work for several hours and have not been able to resolve any possible issues as everything appears to be coded properly according to [jQuery Ajax Call](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.ajax/). From what I can tell the code is not even being executed. However when I manually run the API call I get the following JSON result:

```
<UnitsOfMeasure.UnitsOfMeasureDataWithMessage xmlns:i="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns="http://schemas.datacontract.org/2004/07/Corporate.Web.API.DAL">
    <Message/>
    <Success>true</Success>
    <UnitOfMeasureBaseUnitItem i:nil="true"/>
    <UnitOfMeasureBaseUnitList i:nil="true"/>
    <UnitOfMeasureRelatedUnitItem i:nil="true"/>
    <UnitOfMeasureRelatedUnitList i:nil="true"/>
    <UnitOfMeasureSetItem i:nil="true"/>
    <UnitOfMeasureSetList i:nil="true"/>
    <UnitOfMeasureTypeItem i:nil="true"/>
    <UnitOfMeasureTypeList i:nil="true"/>
    <UsedForID>d64d99f9-acfa-44cd-a199-4557b7b20912</UsedForID>
</UnitsOfMeasure.UnitsOfMeasureDataWithMessage>
```

My API Code is as follows:

```
[Route("api/admin/UnitsOfMeasure/UnitOfMeasureDefaultUsedForGetID")]
[HttpGet]
[ResponseType(typeof(UnitsOfMeasure.UnitsOfMeasureDataWithMessage))]
public IHttpActionResult UnitOfMeasureDefaultUsedForGetID(string UnitOfMeasureDefaultUsedForName)
{
    UnitsOfMeasure _oUnitsOfMeasure = new UnitsOfMeasure();
    return Ok(_oUnitsOfMeasure.UnitsOfMeasureSet_GetUsedForID(UnitOfMeasureDefaultUsedForName));
}
```

My DAL is supposed to return a Boolean flag and a Guid.

And my Ajax call is as follows:

```
$.ajax({
    type: "GET",
    url: g_WebServiceUnitOfMeasureDefaultUsedForGetIDURL,
    data: {"UnitOfMeasureDefaultUsedForName": "Purchase"},
    datatype: "json",
    success: function(jsonResult){
        DefaultUnitUsedForID = jsonResult;
    },
    failure: function (xhr, textStatus, errorThrown) {
        console.log(xhr);
        console.log("---------------------------------------------------------------------------");
        console.log(textStatus);
        console.log("---------------------------------------------------------------------------");
        console.log(errorThrown);
        console.log("---------------------------------------------------------------------------");
    },
    error: function (xhr, textStatus, errorThrown) {
        console.log(xhr);
        console.log("---------------------------------------------------------------------------");
        console.log(textStatus);
        console.log("---------------------------------------------------------------------------");
        console.log(errorThrown);
        console.log("---------------------------------------------------------------------------");
    }});
```

As mentioned, from stepping through the code, it does not even enter the success or failure functions. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: what errors does the console shows in the web developer tool ? 404 ?

Comment: nothing, no errors. the debugger completely bypasses the ajax call after the first line of the call.

Comment: In Chrome debugger open the network tab and see if the request is made by the browser

Comment: I stepped through with VS2013 and it looks like the call is executing, however on the web site, nothing happens.

Comment: @RaviKumarMistry there is an entry for the specified execution, still no data is being returned.

Comment: What is the status of request in console network tab

Comment: try removing the datatype from the client (let the browser work it out) and put a break point inside your API method to see if the request actually makes it through the servers routing. If you can see the GET going out on the browsers network tab then you are either sending it to the wrong URL (I am assuming that you are not) or the server side routing engine did not match what you sent to the API method you think. until the request hits your break point and you see a response messages going back your not going to get a response.

Comment: @RaviKumarMistry 200-OK

Comment: put a break point or alert(); in the success block and see if it executing the block

Comment: @RaviKumarMistry - Ive done that and still no dice.

Comment: @CodeUniquely - Tried that and still no dice.

Comment: use Firefox with firebug that may help to you find the issue

Comment: @Vijay - No indication as to what the problem is. The only error that popped up was something to do with a different issue.

Comment: John,

public IHttpActionResult UnitOfMeasureDefaultUsedForGetID(string UnitOfMeasureDefaultUsedForName = "")

and
use
$.ajax({
    type: "GET",
    url: g_WebServiceUnitOfMeasureDefaultUsedForGetIDURL,
    data: {"UnitOfMeasureDefaultUsedForName": "Purchase"},
    datatype: "json",
    success: function(jsonResult){
        DefaultUnitUsedForID = jsonResult;
    },
   error: function(e){
    }


remove failure

Comment: @Vijay - No change in results

Comment: would you please check web config for you api, that may be restrict your  Ajax call,

check it firebug show any warning message

Comment: I think I may have solved the problem. I have `DefaulUnitUsedForID` defined outside in this example and that is causing problems. Once I move the declaration into the success function, It is now returning the Guid I am after. However, now I am getting an error stating that it is undefined outside.

Answer (score 0):

May be it is foolish, But give it a shoot

```
$.get( g_WebServiceUnitOfMeasureDefaultUsedForGetIDURL,
{"UnitOfMeasureDefaultUsedForName": "Purchase"} )
.done(function( data ) {
DefaultUnitUsedForID = jsonResult;
alert( "Data Loaded: " + data );
});
```

Comment: what is the version of jquery?

Comment: This is what we call a bad day, You are doing everything right ,Try some foolish thing don't think wisely because sometimes it solve my problems. ;P